# Date parameter expression(s) - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am struggling to work out how to get an SSRS report's date parameters to default to the:

**Date 1**: Last day of the previous month - in the previous year.

so for example today = 22/06/2021 - I'd need 31/05/2020 to appear

**Date 2**: Last day of the current month - in the previous year.

So for example today = 22/06/2021 - I'd need 30/06/2020 to appear.

any assistance gratefully received. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always find it is easier to first change the date to the first of the current month and go from there. I used to use DATEADD but have started using the VB.NET way - it's actually easier for complicated calculations like this.

For the first of the current month:

```
=DATEADD("d", 1 - DAY(TODAY))
```

OR

```
=TODAY.AddDays(1 - TODAY.Day)
```

Then subtract a year:

```
=DATEADD("y", -1, DATEADD("d", 1 - DAY(TODAY)))
```

OR

```
=TODAY.AddDays(1 - TODAY.Day).AddYears(-1)
```

Then subtract a day from that to get the end of the previous month:

```
=DATEADD("d", -1, DATEADD("y", -1, DATEADD("d", 1 - DAY(TODAY))))
```

OR

```
=TODAY.AddDays(1 - TODAY.Day).AddYears(-1).AddDays(-1)
```

For the last day of current month in previous year, a month should be added before subtracting the day:

```
=DATEADD("d", -1, DATEADD("M", 1, DATEADD("y", -1, DATEADD("d", 1 - DAY(TODAY)))))
```

OR

```
=TODAY.AddDays(1 - TODAY.Day).AddYears(-1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

The VB.NET is easier to read and can be calculated as you read it while reading the nested DATEADDs is more difficult.

Comment: thank you for taking the time and trouble to get back

Comment: Good answer. I often forget to use the VB.NET methods. You could actually shorten the last expression too slightly . `=TODAY.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(TODAY.Day * -1)`

Answer (score 1):

For the fist expression use

```
=
DateAdd(
        DateInterval.Day,
        day(today()) * -1,
        DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, today())
       )
```

for the 2nd use

```
=
DateAdd(
        DateInterval.Day,
        Day(today()) * -1,
        DateAdd(
                DateInterval.Month, 
                1,
                DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, today())
                )
        )
```

In the first expression starting in he middle and working outwards.

Use DateAdd to subtract 1 year from today's date, then subtract the current day number (22) from this.

The 2nd is..
Subtract 1 year from today's date, then add one month to it, then finally subtract the current day number.

Comment: thanks very much for taking the trouble to answer - much appreciated